# Enrich the couchdb User Context Object?? (Or other way to store user data server side)

Tags: couchdb, replication

We are using CouchDB to sync data between an a medical record and clients and want to include a subset of data on the client side. 
Each client needs access to data identified by a set of patient ids. We would prefer to avoid include the patient id set in the request query during replication as this would consume a lot of bandwidth (this is in a low connectivity setting in Kenya). Is there a way to store this data somewhere on the server side (say the user context object?) such that the replication filter function could have access to the data?